# How to use provider in a builder? FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, builder, provider, stateless

As a hobby and with the purpose of being better with provider I'm converting all the stateful widgets that I like into stateless widgets using provider.
I perfectly understand simple cases, but now I have a problem with provider in builder.
Here is where I use the provider (flipCardProvider.isBack)

[Use Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT8uX.jpg)

And the error is the next one:

[Provider Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmfMN.jpg)

Comment: To improve the question I'd suggest you use code snippets instead of screenshots, there's a capability to outline them in code blocks. Same about error logs, it's worth having it as a separate blick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think calling `notifyListeners()` in builder is the right place, there must be a general design flaw and misconception about how the framework works.
Yet as a workaround you can wrap the call in `Timer()` or `Future.delayed()` to have the update scheduled right after build() completion:

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 0, () => notifyListeners())
```

Comment: You are right! notifyListeners() in builder is not a right place! What I did (and it worked) is only delete all the notifyListeners() in builder!